# C++ Saving bytes to file with as little size as possible

Tags: c++, windows, serialization

I have 492383 vectors. Each vector contains 52 unsigned chars.

When I serialize them to a file, the file size is around 25 mb.
This perfectly matches 492383 * 52 bytes.

However I would like to ask if there is a way to store it in a more space efficient way without 7zipping it or so. I mean just by encoding or so.

I think not, but I wanted to ask anyway.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Zipping, etc. **is** encoding.

Comment: Do the char vectors have common suffixes, prefixes, or otherwise common anything?

Comment: struct ByteFeature
{
 unsigned char Features[53];
}; But I simply store the bytes in a file one after another. No special formatting is used.

Comment: Are all 256 possible values used for every single position? Are all arrays completely different from one another? Why the array contains 53 bytes, but you say it's 52?

Comment: If you don't need all the chars, just some "until a null" then you might be able to just write out until a null, each entry one after another...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mistyped... Features[52] would be correct. All 256 values are used. Not all arrays are different. I know what you are thinking :-)

Comment: "Not all arrays are different" - so some are the same?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No!

Long answer: Yes, but the encoding is no different than using zipping and similar technieques. Zipping is nothing but encoding your data to a format which is smart enough to recognize patterns to reduce the size of your files.

If you're unhappy about using an external program for zipping; simply use a library that would do that for you, like [this one](http://www.libarchive.org/), and merge it within your program.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple, but fairly efficent, encoding is something called "[byte-pair encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_pair_encoding)", and it works really well with certain types of data, such as text, because there are usually plenty of "unused bytes" in a sequence.

A BPE encoder/decoder can be implemented in a few dozen lines of code, so compared with a `zip` type archive, it is quite small.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe - depends on the nature of the data being stored.

Anyway - why worry over a 25mb of data?